# Как изменить цвет рамки выделенного кода Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Возник вопрос касательно изменения цвета полосы выделенного кода в visual studio. Как изменить цвет той рамки, которая появляется, когда вы переносите каретку на определённую строчку кода?

[image: Всего три строки и эта рамка находится на первой строке]

Comment: [Change visual studio caret color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842760/change-visual-studio-caret-color)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Средства > Параметры > Окружение > Шрифты и цвета

Параметры для: Текстовый редактор

Отображаемые элементы > 'Выделить текущую строку' (элемент списка)

Установите 'Основной цвет элемента' в любой удобный для вас цвет. Этот параметр меняет цвет границы текущей строки.

Установите 'Фоновый цвет элемента' в любой удобный для вас цвет. Этот параметр меняет внутренний цвет строки.